# Trying to change the cursor, doesn't work for terminator

Tags: vim, terminal

this piece of .vimrc is for changing cursor shape. It works showing the underscore cursor in xterm, but in terminator not...Any idea? I tried it changing xterm by terminator but it doesn't work..

```
if &term =~ '^xterm'
  " solid underscore
  let &t_SI .= "\<Esc>[4 q"
  " solid block
  let &t_EI .= "\<Esc>[2 q"
  " 1 or 0 -> blinking block
  " 3 -> blinking underscore
endif
```

Javi

Comment: What does `:set term?` show to you?

Comment: hmm - do not get it to work. i assume you have the code snippet from http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Configuring_the_cursor, the colors do actually work; I use green for insert and orange for normal mode - that is visual enough to distinguish the modes - though an ibeam would be nice in insert mode. @dusan `set term? -> xterm` at my setup.

Comment: @dusan term=xterm . Yes im using that snippet, yes the snippet below in that page works as you say...

Comment: when i googled the other day i, i saw there were some issues with terminator a few years back, don't know if they were solved, but `man terminator` shows there is an option to change the cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CSI 4 SP q` is a specific sequence recognised by xterm to change the cursor shape. If it doesn't work for your terminal, it likely that your terminal simply doesn't recognise it.

Comment: Terminator doesn't support these escape sequences, which seem specific to xterm. Unfortunately the support would have to be added in libVTE, which Terminator and gnome-terminal both use.